# Ansible: when condition with_items

Tags: ansible

I have such a part of a playbook, which works fine:

```
- name: "Copy solrconfig.xml"
  copy:
    src: "{{role_path}}/files/{{item.path}}"
    dest: "{{solr_jmx_config}}/solrconfig.xml"
  with_items:
    - path: solrconfig_master.xml
  when: inventory_hostname == "{{ solr_master }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: solr

- name: "Copy solrconfig.xml"
  copy:
    src: "{{role_path}}/files/{{item.path}}"
    dest: "{{solr_jmx_config}}/solrconfig.xml"
  with_items:
    - path: solrconfig_slave.xml
  when: inventory_hostname != "{{ solr_master }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: solr
```

However, I would like it to look nicer and do something like that:

```
- name: "Copy solrconfig.xml"
  copy:
   src: "{{role_path}}/files/{{item.path}}"
   dest: "{{solr_jmx_config}}/solrconfig.xml"
  with_items:
   - path: solrconfig_master.xml -> when: inventory_hostname == "{{ solr_master }}"
   - path: solrconfig_slave.xml ->  when: inventory_hostname != "{{ solr_master }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: solr
```

How to apply "when" condition for each particular item?

Best regards,
Marek

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `with_items` and `role_path` here? Try this:

```
- name: "Copy solrconfig.xml"
  copy:
    src: "{{ 'solrconfig_master.xml' if inventory_hostname == solr_master else 'solrconfig_slave.xml' }}"
    dest: "{{solr_jmx_config}}/solrconfig.xml"
  become: yes
  become_user: solr
```

`with_` is generally used for loops, you don't need it for single element.
When you call tasks inside roles, search path for file modules include `<role_path>/files/...`.

Comment: Hi Konstantin,  that approach actually worked for me. Thanks for an answer!